Selenium wire hide redundant logging
I am using SeleniumWire, Django, Celery for parsing
I have a lot of redundant logs from selenium-wire. I mean logs:
Capturing request: sitename
Capturing response: sitename 200 OK

I want to hide these logs. How to configure logger/driver to hide selenium-wire logs?
I am using regular logger:
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


My Django logging settings:
# settings.py

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s- %(message)s'
        },
    },
    # django uses some of its own loggers for internal operations. In case you want to disable them just replace the False above with true.
    # A handler for DEBUG. It is basically writing the DEBUG messages into a file called DJANGO_DEBUG.log
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    # A logger for DEBUG which has a handler called 'file'. A logger can have multiple handler
    'loggers': {
       # notice the blank '', Usually you would put built in loggers like django or root here based on your needs
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}


looks like Selenium Wirer logger config  issue

You can either set this
1. in Django logging settings
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'seleniumwire': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'WARNING',  # Change to WARNING or ERROR to suppress INFO logs
        'propagate': False,
    },
},

2. at a Python level
import logging
import seleniumwire

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
seleniumwire_logger = logging.getLogger('seleniumwire')
seleniumwire_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)


It looks like you need to override the selenium wire logger
selenium_logger = logging.getLogger('seleniumwire')
selenium_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

see : https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/62
